# How to search and replace text in multiple lines in SVG effectively?

Tags: svg, replace, translation, inkscape

Say I have an SVG file like this:

[image]

How should I edit the content of the text effectively? Clicking each of them in an SVG editor is a way, but if you have many text like this it will be ineffectively. One can search and replace it in the source, but for texts that span in two or more lines, they are separated:

```
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="text1769"
   style="font-size:2.82222px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;text-align:center;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1771);display:inline"
   transform="matrix(2.5377821,0,0,2.5377821,-1.6795872,-19.146171)"><tspan
     x="2.7854152"
     y="13.211847"><tspan>A sentence spans </tspan></tspan><tspan
     x="7.1944451"
     y="16.739622"><tspan>in two lines</tspan></tspan></text>
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="text1775"
   style="font-size:2.82222px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;text-align:center;white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect1777);display:inline"
   transform="matrix(2.5377821,0,0,2.5377821,-13.399482,-7.1235831)"><tspan
     x="11.339253"
     y="19.647394"><tspan>An one liner</tspan></tspan></text>
```

Is there a way so that texts that span across multiple lines can be easily recognized and edited as if they are just one line? My purpose is to translated [this file](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/144540/26474) to another language.

Comment: Please read about [<foreignObject>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject). You can use a `<foreignObject>` to include elements from a different XML namespace - for example HTML. For example you can have a `<p>` inside a a `<foreignObject>`

Comment: cool. Is there a way to convert a normal SVG file to foreignObject?

Comment: I imagine you'd need to write some bespoke code to do it in a language of your choice.

Comment: You could make one text item per line, perhaps? That could be the quickest way, in combination, for example, with https://gitlab.com/Moini/nextgenerator .

I believe the Inkscape extensions library can also detect text contents.

Search and replace in Inkscape recognizes linebreaks, too.